# Spinner shows the selected item in Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-spinner

In my program I have a spinner that show three `String`s taken from an `Arraylist<String>`. I use this code:

```
pinnerArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    spinnerArray.add("IT");
    spinnerArray.add("EN");
    spinnerArray.add("PR");

    ArrayAdapter lenguageAdapter=new ArrayAdapter(convertView.getContext(), R.layout.lenguage_item_layout, spinnerArray);
    holder.spinnerLenguage.setAdapter(lenguageAdapter);
```

My spinner initially shows `IT` and, when I click on it, opens the list of items. In this list there are all 3 items (`IT`, `EN`, `PR`) but I want show the selected item (in this case `IT`) only one time and not two times.

How can I correct my code?

Comment: If you mean that it's showing "IT" as selected as well as displaying it in the drop-down list, that's just the way Android displays spinners. That's how it works in my apps as well.

Comment: Uhm exist a solution for doesn't show "IT" (or the selected item) in the drop-down list?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. The `Spinner` view relies on an array of Strings to populate both the drop-down list and the selected value. When you select list item 1, it uses the value from list item 1 to populate the value in the dropdown as well as the selected item. If you remove it one place, you also remove it in the other.

Comment: Uhm, exist another solution that not use the spinner but that have similar result?